# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator" Error

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I am writing a query to return only those rows which contains alphanumeric values.
Please Tell me if you can resolve this ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.
What could be the reason for this error

```
create table alpha_numeric(col1 varchar2(20));


insert into alpha_numeric values ('1000');
insert into alpha_numeric values ('a1093b');
insert into alpha_numeric values ('19b45');
insert into alpha_numeric values ('231');
insert into alpha_numeric values ('1000cc');
insert into alpha_numeric values ('a1000');
commit;

select * from alpha_numeric
where translate(col1,'1234567890',' ');
```

Answer (score 4):

you should put here relational operator (=,<,>,etc.):

```
where translate(col1,'1234567890',' ') = ...;
```